# Should there be tag for the [John-Wick-series]

Tags: discussion, tags

There have been a few questions related to the world beyond the character of John Wick. Questions regarding the organization of the enigmatic High Table and the operations of the Continental Hotel expand beyond the scope of one movie in the franchise. Questions with this level of scope get tagged with two or all three of the franchise's films, but would have to be updated if the topics are covered in future movies.

Should a dedicated [john-wick-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-wick-series) tag be created to accommodate this. If not, how many movies in the franchise would need to exist before such a tag is allowed? The precedent is set with tags like [star-wars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) or [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) but these franchises span dozens of films or TV shows that the three John Wick movies does not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Probably not necessary

We already have the [john-wick](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-wick) tag which serves our *dual* purpose of referring to not only the first movie but also the series as a whole.

As you mentioned we have a precedent with the [star-wars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) tag which is NOT [star-wars-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-series)

> An epic space opera film **series** created by George Lucas. Use this tag when asking questions about Star Wars. If you're asking about a particular movie, also tag the question with the tag for that movie.

Comment: Forgot to mark this accepted. My bad